# How to fix 'Permission Denied' when using csshX

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to ssh into multiple boxes using csshX. When I try individually using `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ~/.ssh/co-user co_user@`, it works.But when I use  `csshX --login co_user co_user@10.32.189.44`, I get

```
Warning: Permanently added '10.32.189.44' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
CHILD at /usr/local/bin/csshX line 1256.

[Process completed]
```

Should I mention as a parameter the public key path for co_user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--ssh_args` where you can accommodate your path to your key (`-i ~/.ssh/co-user`.

Running [`csshX`](https://github.com/brockgr/csshx/blob/master/csshX)`--ssh_args "-i ~/.ssh/co-user" --login co_user co_user@10.32.189.44` should do the job.